# Do we have better way to simplify this code?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

viewModel.sectionTypeId, specialSectionId, specialSectionId -> These values are commonly used both cases

```
if (data.section_type == "customized") {
        viewModel.sectionTypeId = data.id ?: 0
        viewModel.specialSectionId = data.id ?: 0
        viewModel.specialSectionName = data.name ?: ""
    } else {
        viewModel.specialSectionId = 0
        viewModel.specialSectionName = ""
        viewModel.sectionTypeId = 0
    }
```

Comment: There are different ways you could rearrange the logic but none that I would consider any simpler. I suppose you could move one of the ID assignments out of the if/else and set it equal to the other ID since they’re the same. That would save you a line of code. But I would wrap this whole thing in `with(viewModel) {}` to clean it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
viewModel.apply {
        val customized = data.section_type == "customized"
        sectionTypeId = if(customized) data.id ?: 0 else 0
        specialSectionId = if(customized) data.id ?: 0 else 0
        specialSectionName = if(customized) data.name ?: "" else ""
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no ternary operator in kotlin, you can use if expressions and assign repeated code to values like this:

```
viewModel.apply {
    val customized = data.section_type == "customized"
    val iD = if(customized) data.id ?: 0 else 0
    sectionTypeId = iD
    specialSectionId = iD
    specialSectionName = if(customized) data.name ?: "" else ""
}
```